# Ruby Shoes - Scrollbars in Subpane window

Tags: ruby, shoes

I can't seem to get a scrollbar to work in an inner stack/flow.  Does anyone know how to?

Comment: shoes appears to be a ruby ui toolkit.

Comment: It is. Its mad scientist, _why, is a real nice guy and he frequents the Ruby List often and answers questions. I don't know if he hangs out on this site, though, so you may want to try http://www.ruby-forum.com/forum/4

Answer (score 5):

Just fix height and add ":scroll => true" parameter:

```
Shoes.app(:title => "Scrolll!" ) do
  flow :margin => 10 do
    stack :width => "150px", :height => "200px", :scroll => true do
      para  "all you need is love",  "all you need is love", "all you need is love", "all you need is love", "all you need is love", "all you need is love", "all you need is love", "all you need is love", "all you need is love", "all you need is love",
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `<div>` tag, and then have CSS as such:

```
#my_div {
 width: [some_width]px;
 height: [some_height]px;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "an inner stack/flow", but we use iframes for our subpane windows which has a scrolling attribute you can set. Otherwise you can use a javascript framework like YUI to get subpane windows that can allow scrolling capabilities.

Comment: The "shoes" tag on the question implies that it's a Shoes stack or flow.